# Rectangle border into 4 equal pieces Illustator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, borders

I want to cut this rectangle border shape(Picture below) into 4 pieces without affecting the gradient color but cannot figure out how. I have tried pathfinder tool, scissors tool, removing anchors. Does anyone have any idea how?

[image]

Comment: First you have to copy the gradient 4 times and re-spread it.

Comment: You could try making four copies and using clipping masks.  Kind of a hacky approach, but should work.

Comment: @Wildcard - actually, not just hacky but possibly the only approach that would really work. If the closed path were cut into separate lines, the mitre joins would not survive

Comment: @BillyKerr isn’t there some tool to outline a path or convert a path to an object?

Comment: @Wildcard, yes, you can expand the stroke to outlines using *Object > Expand*

Comment: Because t's a stroke **along** the path, expanding will result in a **Gradient Mesh** which **can't** be divided. Masks are honestly your best bet.. or recreating each section manually.

Comment: Clipping mask solution is the best one I think @Wildcard Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the object in place four times, and put a different clipping mask on each of the four copies.  Voila.

As discussed in comments, this may actually be the *only* way to accomplish this outcome without manually recreating the gradient.